# I cannot make userMapper.kt(interface) used in servicePackage when I using Mybatis

Tags: java, kotlin, mybatis, mapper, kotlin-lateinit

Although I had marked 'lateinit',it's still not initialized.
It's one ghost bug,last night everything is OK,but today it's can't work,it's so tired[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wv1gY.png)

Comment: please provide an example of your code. it is nigh impossible to help without your code snippet.

Comment: there has one img's url,I don't know how to display it

Answer (score 0):

It is not initialized *because* you marked it `lateinit` and never actually initialized it.

You still need some method which will do `userMapper = ...`, and you must call this method before you can call `userCheck`.

But it would be better to remove `lateinit` and initialize in the constructor.